# Удаление обьета в Java Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Я создал выстрел пули:

```
List<String> bullets = new ArrayList<>();

for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
    bullet.x = bullet.x + 10; 
    System.out.println(bullet.x);
    batch.draw(tbullet, bullet.x, bullet.y);
}
```

Как удалить объект(пулю), когда она вылетает за экран?

У меня получилось так:

```
for (Iterator<Bullet> iterator = bullets.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Bullet bullet = iterator.next();
    if (bullet.x>=500) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Но:

Во первых :  этот вариант работает, но его заминусовали.

Во вторых : после первой первой перезагрузки Android studio появилась такая ошибка:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:core:assemble, :desktop:assemble]
Information:Modules "core", "desktop" were fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:20.08.2016 1:13 - Compilation completed with 72 errors and 1 warning in 4s 324ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Warning:Gradle: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
D:\mk3Clone\core\src\com\mk3clone\game\mk3main.java
Error:(62, 39) Gradle: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
Error:(78, 35) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 36) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 37) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 38) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 39) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 40) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(78, 41) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(129, 16) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(129, 17) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(129, 18) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(129, 19) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(135, 16) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(135, 17) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(135, 18) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(135, 19) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 24) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 25) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 26) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 27) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 28) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(153, 29) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(157, 24) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(157, 25) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(157, 26) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(157, 27) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(157, 28) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 17) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 18) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 19) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 20) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 21) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 22) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 23) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(162, 24) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 52) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 53) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 54) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 55) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 56) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 57) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 58) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 59) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 61) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 62) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 64) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 65) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 67) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 68) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 69) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 70) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(245, 71) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 32) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 33) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 34) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 35) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 36) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 37) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(246, 38) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 48) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 49) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 50) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 51) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 52) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(248, 53) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 40) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 41) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 42) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 43) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 44) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
Error:(258, 45) Gradle: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

Как всетаки создать, а потом удалить обьект в Java?

ps.Русские буквы я убрал.

Comment: В начале ты создаёшь список строк (List<String> bullets), а потом итерируешь как Bullet bullet ?!

Answer (score 2):

Ну попробуй так:

```
List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
        Bullet bullet = bullets.get(i);
        bullet.x = bullet.x + 10;
        if (bullet.x >= 500)
            bullets.remove(i);
        System.out.println(bullet.x);
        batch.draw(tbullet, bullet.x, bullet.y);
    }
```